# What about the profiles here, with shadow?

Tags: support, user-card

Sometimes I see avatar's users with shadow, and if you hover your mouse on them, they expand with a small bio.

Does that feature have a name? Which are the requirements to get that on your profile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is part of the [established user privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) - once you earn enough reputation, you too will have a user-card.